# Ruby on Rails uniqueness validation fails but record is still created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, unique

I am trying to require unique email addresses for a record in my RoR project, I have the following validation in place:

```
validates :email, presence: { :message => "You must provide an email address." }, uniqueness: { :message => "This email is already taken." }
validates_uniqueness_of :email, :message=>"This email is already taken"
```

Next to the form to add a record is a list of recently added entries. When I try to save a new record it renders the form over with an error however if you look at the list the item (with the duplicate email address) has been added. If you refresh the page or change the email in the form and resubmit the entry disappears from the list. I'm curious why it seems like the record is being saved even though the validation is firing properly.

I had thought it could be that I was creating the object with `object.create(params)` however when I changed that to `object.build(params)` it had no effect. All help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is not a problem with your validation, but with the way how you render that list.

If you add your object to the list even if the validation was not successful than that element will be rendered exactly like all other elements in that list (since it has all nessessary values).

You can use the following methods to exclude such elements from a list or to handle them in a different way - grey out for example:

```
record.valid?      # returns true if the record is valid
record.persisted?  # returns true if the record exists in the database (was save)
```

whereas:

```
record.new_record? # returns true if the record wasn't saved into the database
```

By the way: You mix up the new and the old hash syntax in your validator definitions and the uniqueness validator is defined twice. You can change that to:

```
validates :email, presence:   { message: 'You must provide an email address.' },
                  uniqueness: { message: 'This email is already taken.' }
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I'm just not entirely clear on how I would use those methods to exclude records. Is there a way to incorporate those methods into `.where()`?

Comment: @apardes: Do you want to show unsaved records in that list (perhaps in a different style)? Or should that records be excluded from the list? Furthermore: Please post your controller and view code. Than I can tell you what to change depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

**create** method creates an object and saves it to the database;

**build** method(Alias for: **new**) won't "create" a record in database, just create a new object in memory.

Validations are used to ensure that only valid data is saved into your database, validations are run before the record are sent to the database. Only Some methods will trigger validations.

1. create
2. create!
3. save
4. save!
5. update
6. update!